# Docker: rename single file with dynamic name to a Static name

Tags: docker

I have an undeterministic script that outputs a json file with a dynamic name in the working directory ie `foo.bar.baz.json` is there a way to copy/paste this file and give it another name, say `output.json`?

I tried:

```
ADD ./*.json output.json
```

but I can see no additional file is added when I `ls` after.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! COPY/ADD work on source directory -> image directories. Here I needed to run the copy inside the buid. This did it:

```
RUN cp /out/*.json /out/output.json
```